# iptables: Failure when trying to block port access for most IP addresses, except for a few

Tags: iptables, ip, port, ipset

I am using `Debian 8 linux`.

I'm trying to block input access to a few ports for most IP addresses, except for a small, select list of IP addresses. I am doing the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
% sudo /sbin/iptables -v -A INPUT -p tcp -m set '!' --match-set allow-list src -m multiport --dports 110,143,993,995 -j DROP
```

Whenever there is an access attempt to any of those ports from an IP address that is not in `allow-list`, that attempt is still succeeding.

These are the first few lines of `allow-list`:

```
% sudo /sbin/ipset list allow-list
Name: allow-list
Type: hash:net
Revision: 6
Header: family inet hashsize 16384 maxelem 262144
Size in memory: 687888
References: 2
Members:
125.8.0.0/13
160.94.0.0/15
104.37.68.0/22
205.233.22.0/23
[ ... more CIDR entries ... ]
```

And this is the current iptables configuration:

```
% sudo /sbin/iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! match-set allow-list src multiport dports pop3,imap2,imaps,pop3s

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realize what I was doing incorrectly. The following fix works for me:

```
% sudo /sbin/iptables -v -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,143,993,995                                   -j DROP
% sudo /sbin/iptables -v -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,143,993,995 -m set --match-set allow-list src -j ALLOW
```

In other words, first ***allow*** the IP's in `allow-list` to access via the port list, and ***then*** drop all other IP's who try to access via that port list.

Also, I had originally left out the `-p tcp` option, which is needed when dealing with TCP ports.

**UPDATE**: Originally, I incorrectly used `-A INPUT` above. I have changed it to the correct `-I INPUT`.

**FURTHER UPDATE**: ... and with `-I`, I had to change the of the rules: `DROP` needs to be defined before `ALLOW` in this case.